Manage Multiple JWT Bearer Token for an ASP.NET Core Web API
I'm trying to register 2 .NET Identity Authentication to the same API. I plan to add more in the future.
The idea is to use a first identity to authenticate the API users (the different branches of our group), and then for each branch, an identity for their own users. So in a first part the web app will authenticate in the API through the first Identity (getting access to some common services for all users) and then if branch user authenticates to its dedicated branch identity, he will be able to access his account details.
I am expecting to achieve this using 2 JWT token: 1 to access the common services, 1 to access branch dedicated services.
I have created my 2 identity projects, and I inject them into my API.

Code to inject the first identity (the common one):
public static class ApiIdentityServicesRegistration
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddApiIdentityServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.Configure<JwtSettings>(configuration.GetSection("ApiJwtSettings"));
        services.AddDbContext<ApiDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("API_IDENTITY"));
        });

        services.AddIdentity<ApiApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApiDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddTransient<IApiUserRepository, UserService>();

        services
            .AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer_ApiUser", o =>
        {
            o.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                ValidIssuer = configuration["ApiJwtSettings:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = configuration["ApiJwtSettings:Audience"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["ApiJwtSettings:Key"]))
            };
        });
        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "AajApiToken";
        });

        return services;
    }
}

And here is the second one (the branch one):
public static class AajIdentityServicesRegistration
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddAajIdentityServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.Configure<JwtSettings>(configuration.GetSection("AajJwtSettings"));
        services.AddDbContext<AajDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("AAJ_IDENTITY"));
        });

        services.AddIdentityCore<AajApplicationUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AajDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AajApplicationUser>>();

        services.AddTransient<IAajUserRepository, AajUserService>();

        services
            .AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer_AajUser",o =>
        {
            o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                ValidIssuer = configuration["AajJwtSettingsJwtSettings:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = configuration["AajJwtSettings:Audience"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["AajJwtSettings:Key"]))
            };
        });
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "AajUserToken";
        });
        return services;
    }
}

And then in the API I use
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer_ApiUser")]

to make sure only authorize API user will access the common services.
When testing, I can login, using the main Identity. I got my token without issue, but when I try to use common services, I got a 401 error without any specific error message.
Note 1: I keep different identity for each branch because user class fields and claims type are very different from branch to branch. Also, some user may be registered in 2 different branches, expecting different services for each.
Note 2: I have tested my API without [Authorize] and it was working fine.
I didn't try much as I can't get any details on that error. I have no idea of how I can debug this [Authorize] feature.

Side note: You can add the language to code blocks for syntax highlighting in the rendered code block. I added c# to them.

You say you receive a "401 error". You mean a HTTP 401 Unauthorized result, right?

You did not disclose the request you make to test it. Are you trying to send a request with both bearer tokens? Does [Authorize] support such a use case? Or do you alternative between the tokens?

If the claim types are very different you could still use different claims instead of implementing a separate identity service, right? (I don't see the need from that alone.)

@Kissaki thanks for the tip and here are the replies to your questions:

yes 401 unauthorized
at the moment I am just sending with one bearer token only. This first test is to see if  [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer_ApiUser")] is working as expected (selecting the correct scheme)



I agree for the claims, but my main problem is that each branch has its own identity tables, with it is own users. On the top I have the API users (which are different). So I couldn't find other possibilities but adding a second identity. Is it possible to manage more than 1 identity tables set into the same Identity service?
Thanks for your help


Yes, instead of using the default identity service implementation you can use your own and handle both stores within the same identity service. You show how you set up both, with AddTransient<IApiUserRepository, UserService>, AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApiDbContext>(), and AddDefaultTokenProviders();. Without looking deeply at the ref docs, UserStore is your own type, right? The interface is not referenced in your code nor a standard type. The dependency injection framework allows you to replace parts or all of the identify service types with your own.

Thanks for help I am going to try this, and I will update you here later


2 JWT token: 1 to access the common services, 1 to access branch
dedicated services.

In my humble opinion, we could set different claims into the jwt token instead of using 2 different authorization mechanisms. For APIs, it can authorize different policy or claims to control the accessibility. In your scenario, it's the identity for the different branches of your group. Maybe we can add a claim to clarify the ideneity/group/branch then validate the claim by adding policy.
If we do require to use different kinds of jwt tokens in the sample API project, for example using different issuers, then we can follow this document to add different auth schemes like
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Audience = "https://localhost:5000/";
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000/identity/";
        })
        .AddJwtBearer("AzureAD", options =>
        {
            options.Audience = "https://localhost:5000/";
            options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/eb971100-7f436/";
        });


Per my understanding, in most of the scenarios, we could use different claims in the token so that we could only use one JWT auth scheme. But if we have different issue/audience which making us have to have multiple authorization mechanisms, then we can follow the document to add double .AddJwtBearer into the app. Please correct me if I misunderstood your requirement. Thanks a lot

thanks for the reply.
Just like I explaining when replying to Kissaki, I manage different user tables, one for each branch plus one for the API user access (basically a simple list of the user that represent the branch themselves).
So if I try to use a unique identity service, can I access all those identity tables set under the same identity service?
Thanks for your help

I have check the link you sent, so I may have misunderstood the meaning of an auth scheme, but I thought it means a different way to authenticate (token, login, 3rd party etc ) but I don't think it is possible to register 2 set of identity tables. Is it?

Hi @CharlesM, I'm not very sure why you need 2 tables for storing users. But tables in database are used to store data. The logic are realized by our codes. The authentication itself is just trying to validate the user, maybe comparing the incoming userName & password with the one stored in data table, your codes control it, so that it is always possible to do it. Then when the user passed the validation, you should know which kind of token you should give to this user account. Then your API shall validate the token just like API is validating who is trying to call it.

My problem is that those user tables (1 for each branch) already exist. I can't merge them (company policy). So, I need to find a way to make all working together.

Is it possible for you to identify the user account in the request should belong to table1 or table 2? If you can, then you can directly validate it, if not, maybe we need to firstly searching in table 1 whether this user existed in it, if not then searching in table 2. No matter how many tables you are having now.

Let's assume a simple scenario, you have 2 tables used for storing user information, users in table one are in format user@aa.com, and users in table 2 are  in format user@brunch.aa.com. When users are trying to sign in, they submit user account and password, then in your codes, you should get the user account and query it whether it's in the tables, if yes, then comparing the password stored in table with the password sent in the request. If it passed the validation, then you shall know the user's permission(maybe based on the user role) and create a suitable jwt token for this user.

Thank you I will see how I can implement this.
